# creating a popup without onclick

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a popup inside an async function. The popup would right before creating the election but I am not sure how to handle/call it. The message is always the same

```
import Popup from '../Popup.js'


async function GenerateElection() {
                    

        const election = await Axios.post("/addElection", {electionInfo}, { headers: { "token" : localStorage.getItem("token") }});
```

here where election is called

```
<Button variant = "contained" style = {{width: 150}} onClick={() => {GenerateElection()}}>Generate Election</Button>
```

I have a very basic popup.js page

```
import React from "react";
const Popup = props => {
return (
<div className="popup-box">
  <div className="box">
    <span className="close-icon" onClick={props.handleClose}>x</span>
    Election is being generated, please wait.
  </div>
</div>
);
};
export default Popup;
```

Answer (score 0):

add a variable in the component where there is a button, for example popup, and fill it in as needed. Also, you don't have to use the arrow function in `onClick` if you don't pass parameters.
`onClick={GenerateElection}`

```
  const [popup, setPopup] = useState(null);

  async function GenerateElection() {
    setPopup(<Popup />)
    const election = await Axios
    .post("/addElection", {electionInfo}, {
       headers: { "token" : localStorage.getItem("token")}
      }
    );
    setPopup(null) // for hide
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {popup && popup}
      <Button variant="contained" style={{width: 150}} onClick={GenerateElection} >Generate Election</Button>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: is there any way to make it so they can also exit out of the popup worst case if the election generation fails and it doesnt go away on it's own? Im assuming it would be passing in the state variable in

Answer (score 0):

You can use hook *useRef* to create a reference for *Popup* and after calling function, add the class *.show* to make it visible.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const Popup = props => {
  const popupRef = useRef(null); // Here is a reference
  return (
    <div className="popup-box" ref={popupRef}>
      <div className="box">
        <span className="close-icon" onClick={props.handleClose}>x</span>
        Election is being generated, please wait.
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Popup;
```

and then call synchronous function with Promise instead of async/await

```
function GenerateElection() {
  popupRef.current.classList.add('show');

  Axios.post(*skipped part*).then(res => {
    const election = res.data
  });

<Button onClick={GenerateElection}>Generate Election</Button>
```